# Google maps, clear markers

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I want to clear all existing markers from my map when certain ajax call finishes. I will post the API code and my ajax code:

I load my map at the start of the script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//SETTINGS
$(document).ready(function() {

// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I then do some stuff via ajax and then at the end of the finished ajax call I want to execute clearing of my markers. Look for the comment:

```
//AJAX AUTOCOMPLETE PLUGIN
var a = $('#searchMap2').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/public/index.php/prodajna_mesta/search', 
    minChars: 1,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    //params: { country:'Yes' }, //aditional parameters
    noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
    // callback function:
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/public/index.php/prodajna_mesta/coords",
            context: document.body,
            data: { coords: suggestion.data }
        }).done(function(data) {

                //CLEAR MY MARKERS HERE

            });
        }
    });  
});
```

And this is how I initialize google map after all of this:

```
function initialize() {

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [

    <?php foreach ($records as $value): ?>
        <?php $records = (array)$records; ?>
        ['<?php echo $value->name ?>', <?php echo $value->coords ?>], 
    <?php endforeach; ?>

];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [

    <?php foreach ($records as $value): ?>
        <?php $records = (array)$records; ?>
        ['<div style="height: 80px; white-space: nowrap;" class="info_content"><b><?php echo $value->name; ?></b><br/><br/><?php echo $value->address; ?><br/>T: <?php echo $value->phone; ?></div>'], 
    <?php endforeach; ?>

];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(9);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. var mapMarkers = []; Declare it global
2. push markers to mapMarkers array.
3. In ajax callback, loop all markers in mapMarkers array and set their map property to null.
4. clear the mapMarkers array.

   ```
   var mapMarkers = []; //STEP 1 Global, so that it can be accessed from ajax success callback

   function initialize() {

   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   var mapOptions = {
       mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
   };

   // Display a map on the page
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
   map.setTilt(45);

   // Multiple Markers
   var markers = [

       <?php foreach ($records as $value): ?>
           <?php $records = (array)$records; ?>
           ['<?php echo $value->name ?>', <?php echo $value->coords ?>], 
       <?php endforeach; ?>

   ];

   // Info Window Content
   var infoWindowContent = [

       <?php foreach ($records as $value): ?>
           <?php $records = (array)$records; ?>
           ['<div style="height: 80px; white-space: nowrap;" class="info_content"><b><?php echo $value->name; ?></b><br/><br/><?php echo $value->address; ?><br/>T: <?php echo $value->phone; ?></div>'], 
       <?php endforeach; ?>

   ];

   // Display multiple markers on a map
   var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;



   // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
   for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
       var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
       bounds.extend(position);
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: position,
           map: map,
           title: markers[i][0]
       });

       mapMarkers.push(marker); //STEP 2

       // Allow each marker to have an info window    
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
           return function() {
               infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
               infoWindow.open(map, marker);
           }
       })(marker, i));

       // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
   }

   // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
   var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
       this.setZoom(9);
       google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
   });

   }


   //AJAX AUTOCOMPLETE PLUGIN
   var a = $('#searchMap2').autocomplete({
       serviceUrl: '/public/index.php/prodajna_mesta/search', 
       minChars: 1,
       delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
       //params: { country:'Yes' }, //aditional parameters
       noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
       // callback function:
       onSelect: function(suggestion) {

           $.ajax({
               url: "/public/index.php/prodajna_mesta/coords",
               context: document.body,
               data: { coords: suggestion.data }
           }).done(function(data) {

                   //CLEAR MY MARKERS HERE
                   //STEP 3

                   var len = mapMarkers.length;
                   for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                     mapMarkers[i].setMap(null);
                  }
                  mapMarkers = []; //Empty the array


               });
           }
       });  
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward answer!